# Resources on multi-MCU architecture?

Tags: pcb-design, stm32, pcb-assembly, robotics

I am designing a 6-axis robot arm, and I just finished tuning the control algorithm for a single BLDC using a STM32 MCU. The next step led me to wonder how such system usually works: I don't think my STM32 MCU can drive 6 motors, it simply doesn't have enough PWM timers and pins. I'm suspecting multiple MCUs will have to be used somehow, but I can't seem to find any such examples/tutorials on the web.

How can I use multiple processors if I'm lacking resources?

Comment: *This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.*

Comment: It sounds simple enough to make one MCU send commands to another MCU to make it do stuff. Or to get an MCU with more PWM timers and more pins. What part are you stuck on?

Comment: 6-axis arms tend to use stepper rather than BLDC motors, and tend to have one micro per motor, or a dedicated IC; ST themselves have some drivers https://www.st.com/en/motor-drivers/stepper-motor-drivers.html

Answer (score 2):

In the past I've ran into this problem, with the STM32F's, but the problem wasn't a lack of GPIO's, it was a lack of processor power. I ran two processors on the same board and used the UART's for communication.

You won't find tutorials on this, you'll have to code up your own solution. But if you can code a timer or a BLDC control loop, sending a message from one processor to another  over a UART (or SPI) shouldn't be that hard. Use a hardware UART to take the load off processor.

Also the STM32H7's have a lot more timers than the STM32F4's so you may want to look at those, use the cube mx tool to help you configure the processor or locate the one with the right resources.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the MCU has enough PWM pins, I don't think you want to be snaking around six PWM wires per motor plus power wires plus feedback wires all over your arm.

Nothing magical about it. By calling it "architecture" you're kind of elevating to a higher position than it really is.

What you do is have a master MCU handle communicate the overall arm movement to the slave MCUs of which there is one per motor on a serial bus what to do, where the slave MCUs handle the direct control loop. You could have a dedicated serial line per motor which might be required for very high-speed communications back and forth between master and slave if a lot of feedback is required for whatever reason, but you should probably try and use a bus if you can.

You're probably going to need the slaves to communicate back to the master their status (i.e. what their actual speed and position is under load) in order to allow the master to send new commands to coordinate the movement. You probably don't want the lighter loaded joints to blindly go ahead with the movement when the heavily loaded joint is lagging behind, and you definitely don't want the elbow motor to continue extending the arm and increasing the length of the lever-arm if the shoulder motor is overloaded.